# Why does Cassandra change the partition key?

Tags: cassandra

When creating the following table in C* the primary key is different after creation.

```
CREATE TABLE example (
 section text,
 server text,
 unique_id int,
 column1 text,
 column2 int,
 PRIMARY KEY ((section), server, unique_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (server ASC, unique_id ASC);
```

When I describe that table it appears as though section is not saved as the partition key:

cqlsh:test> describe example;

```
CREATE TABLE test.example (
    section text,
    server text,
    unique_id int,
    column1 text,
    column2 int,
    PRIMARY KEY (section, server, unique_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (server ASC, unique_id ASC)
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: If your partition key consists of only one column putting parenthesis is not needed. The first column of a mult-column priamry key is by default the partition key column. C* simply does not echo back the unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: Ahh, I've either not come across that in the docs or I've forgotten. Thanks :) Please add as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your partition key consists of only one column putting parenthesis is not needed. The first column of a mult-column priamry key is by default the partition key column. C* simply does not echo back the unnecessary parenthesis.

From the CQL 3.1 [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/create_table_r.html):

> PRIMARY KEY is:
>
> [..]
>
> ( column_name1, column_name2, column_name3 ...)
>
> [..]
>
> column_name1 is the partition key.